# With or without preposition are these sentences correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

1.He listens **to** classical music every night.
2.He listens classical music every night.

In the first, the sentence used *the preposition "to"* and in the second, *no preposition* is used.
Are these sentences correct? Do these sentences mean the same? or is any mistake in these sentences with or without preposition?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 2 is incorrect - '*to*' is essential because of the '*classical music*' that follows it. We can say '*Listen!*' without the *'to'* or '*I'm listening.'*, but as soon as we mention whatever the listening refers to, we need the '*to*'! So, *'Listen to that storm!'*,
*'I want you to listen to me, please'*, *'Listen to the announcements'*, and so on.

Comment: 1. If they were now listening, I should be informing them of this circumstance.
2. You must speak in this way, whether they listen or not.                        3. One time he listens, and another time he does not.
4. If such a person as you speak, of course he will listen.

In these sentences why "to" is not used?